# How to filter out "Crawlers"/Image Proxies when tracking email content or links and get ONLY real clicks of the user

Tags: email, php, smtp, tracking, web-crawler

Currently I am working on a feature with which I should be able to track E-Mails and the links in it. So when a user clicks on a link in an image I make some entries in the database so that I can make analysis of users behaviour in emails

When a user clicks on an E-Mail I get the details (link, ip, where the linkn was located, userAgent).

The problem:
After some seconds of the user clicking on the link I get about 2 entires from one click - one entry is the real click with the ip of the user and the second entry is a google-ip - I guess it's google crawler or image proxy server.

I suppose that when Google has such a "mechanism" that others have this too. hotmail, yahoo, gmx, etc and who knows how many others are out there

My question: Is there a good way to get only the real click of the user? I thought of checking the ip and then deciding wether to store the "visit". Checking the User Agent also doesn't really help since it's a "Windows 10 Chrome" User Agent.
Is there a universal way to tackle this issue or do you have some tips?

Just a short info: I am using Laravel 5.7

Any help is much appreciated
Thank you in advance guys!